# Publish build artifacts to github page

Tags: git, jenkins, push, gradle, github-pages

I have project on GitHub which gets build by a Jenkins over at cloudbees.

When ever the build succeeds on the master branch I'd like to update the gh-pages branch and push it to github.

I'm using Gradle as the build tool.

Are there any Gradle and/or Jenkins plugins I can use for that?

Comment: Funny, I thought about exactly the same thing yesterday to publish some Javadocs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [github-pages gradle plugin](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git) that is extremely easy to use to publish documentation to gh-pages branch in gradle builds and I've successfully used it in the past.

Comment: I would love to see a example project implementing that plugin that I could just fork on GitHub and try it.

Comment: I reckon you should be able to set it all up using the docs which contain examples

Comment: I don't agree that it is easy, but I will give it a go.  The documentation is good on how to configure but lacks severely on detail for new users to get the first thing running.

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](http://blog.cgdecker.com/2011/02/deploying-documentation-to-github-pages.html) suggests using the "**Git Publisher post-build action**" in order to register the push action back to `gh-pages` branch.

In the case of the [jdbc-persist](https://github.com/cgdecker/jdbc-persist) project, the approach was to have three jenkins jobs:

- one to generate a maven site and the javadoc
- one to pull the latest gh-pages content, delete everything and replace it by the new updated maven site and javadoc
- one to push back through the "Git Publisher post-build action"

---

Update August 2016: **[Simpler GitHub Pages publishing](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing)** now allows to keep your page files in a subfolder of the *same* branch (no more `gh-pages` needed):

[image: Now you can select a source in your repository settings and GitHub Pages will look for your content there.]

So you could now update the content of a subfolder within the same branch instead of updating a separate branch.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new version of [gradle-git-publish](https://github.com/ajoberstar/gradle-git-publish) plugin